# Template does not exists Error...in Django error while running the manage.py

Tags: python, django

```
{% extends 'chartapp/base.html' %}

<script>
    {% block jquery %}
    {% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div clas = 'col-sm-12'>
        <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is the simple code of chart.html and the structure of the directory is

```
(venv) sevenbits@sevenbits-H110M-H:~/chart-django/chart$ tree
.
├── chart
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── chartapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── chartapp
│   │       ├── base
│   │       │   ├── bootstrap_defaults.html
│   │       │   ├── css.html
│   │       │   └── js.html
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       └── charts.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

This is the urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import HomeView, get_data

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^api/data/$', get_data, name='api-data'),

]
```

This is my views.py file

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

class HomeView(View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                return render(request, 'chartapp/charts.html', {})

def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
                "sales": 100,
                "customers": 10,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

TemplateDoesNotExist at charts.html
This type of error shows while running the code.I have included the template but shows error.This can be template structure error.It would be helpful if someone can guide where i made mistake.

Comment: Can you add your TEMPLATE settings in setting.py file ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `base.html` is in the `chartapp` directory, therefore your `extends` tag should be:

```
{% extends 'chartapp/base.html' %}
```

Comment: Make sure you have saved the changes and restarted the server. The full error message will give you info about which template was not found and which directories Django searched for your template file.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return render(request, 'chartapp/charts.html', {})
```

Comment: Thanks this one solved the error need to include the chartapp.